# Как сделать авторизацию входа в бота с помощью логина и пароля

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite

**Как сделать авторизацию входа в бота с помощью логина и пароля, чтобы каждый раз не вносить user_id новым пользователям?**

Импортировать сразу все логины и пароли в базу данных.
В базе данных будет таблица USERS еде будут два столбца username (логин), password (пароль)

Щас пользуюсь функцией которая авторизует пользователя по user_id и дает доступ функционалу бота:

```
сon = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATA_BASE)
with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("""SELECT user_id FROM USERS""")
    user_ids = [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall()]

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.chat.id not in user_ids)
def access_msg(message):
    core.log(message.chat, message.text)
    msg = "ДОСТУП ЗАБОРОЩЕН"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=msg, parse_mode='HTML')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем принцип такой.

```
сon = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATA_BASE)
cur = con.cursor()
sql = """SELECT full_name from users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?;"""
cur.execute(sql)
if not cur.fetchone():  # An empty result evaluates to False.
    print("Login failed")
else:
    print("Welcome")
```